# Xamarin.Auth linkedin redirectUrl

Tags: xamarin.forms, linkedin-api, oauth-2.0

Welcome All. 
Currently I'm working with Xamarin.Forms.
Could somebody tell mi please how to set redirectUrl in xamarin.auth?
I'm stuck with this one.
Write now I have something like this in my .Droid project:

```
 var authUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization";
 var redirectUrl = "http://localhost:3000/signin_linkedin";
 var tokenUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
 var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                    clientId: "*",
                    clientSecret: "*",
                    scope: "r_basicprofile",
                    authorizeUrl: new System.Uri(authUrl),
                    redirectUrl: new System.Uri(redirectUrl),
                    accessTokenUrl: new System.Uri(tokenUrl));
```

I managed to get LinkedIn login and pass form. 
When I click "Sing in and allow" I get error like:
"The web page at http://localhost:3000/signin_linkedin?code=..."
could not be loaded becouse:
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I think the reason of this behavior is invalid redirectUrl.
Best regards
Michał

Comment: Try use a active domain

Comment: @Bonelol how to do it...I'm stuck with this and don't know what to do. Please help

Comment: Use a real domain instead of localhost, like https://www.linkedin.com/oauth-success

Comment: Thank's that works.